# Android Eclipse design issue

Tags: android

I use eclipse to design and develop anndroid app , but i notice that my design is not compatiable for all android devices .
Is there any method to make the design compatible for all devices?

Comment: each SDK, each company custom Android modifications, etc will produce a different design look. The best way to have a unify look is by using custom views and avoid android normal assets and views. E.g: Same android stock dialog won't look the same on every API

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue of eclipse,

> There is not single method to do this, Please see the android
>   developer's guide,Here is the link for device compatibility

[link here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/compatibility.html)